# put id number in asp form on next page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to pass a known value - my id number - into a field on an asp form on the next page.

When a user clicks on one page in my site, (html or php, whichever is easier) I'd like to put my customer number in an asp form on the next page. This would save the user from doing this, and my 10 digit id number would automatically be input in the form on the next page.

I do not have access to the asp form page.

This is the form field in which I would like to have the text:

```
<input name=RepDID value="" maxlength=20 size=20>
```

I would like it to automatically be populated like this:

```
<input name=RepDID value="myIDnbr123" maxlength=20 size=20>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you will have to somehow pass the id from the previous page to the next page. You can use either hidden elements or session variable to get this value on the next page and then add it to the source.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's what I figured in the abstract, but I am messing up somehow, can you please be more specific? I included the existing code to help.